# Peskin & Schroeder Chapter 16.1 derivation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vectors, scattering, polarization

I am trying to derive the term shown in chapter 16.1 in Peskin & Schroeder. We have defined our polarisation vectors as
$$
\epsilon^+_\mu(k)=\left(\frac{k^0}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k}|},\frac{\vec{k}}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k}|}\right)\;\;\;\epsilon^-_\mu(k)=\left(\frac{k^0}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k}|},-\frac{\vec{k}}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k}|}\right)
$$
Even though I went through the derivation and understand  equations (16.16) and (16.17) I can't seem to get how to derive equation (16.21)
$$
i\mathcal{M}=ig\bar{v}(p_+)\gamma_\rho t^c u(p)\frac{-i}{k_3^2}\epsilon_\mu^{-*}(k_1)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k_2}|}\cdot gf^{abc}k_1^\rho k_1^\mu
$$
I see how this is equal to
$$
i\mathcal{M}=ig\bar{v}(p_+)\gamma_\rho t^c u(p)\frac{-i}{k_3^2}\cdot gf^{abc}k_1^\rho\frac{|\vec{k_1}|}{|\vec{k_2}|}
$$
But I have no clue where the $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k_2}|}$$ factor came from

Comment: I made the same comment in my notes on the book, so it may be an error. But the general argument they make is correct, regardless of whether this is an error or not.

Comment: @Oбжорoв I assumed that it would be the amplitude without replacing $k_{2\nu}$ but still, it doesn't make sense because we still have $k_1^\rho k_1^\mu$ which means that we substituted $k_2$ out. It's true that the argument still works but I'd have an extra factor of $\sqrt{2}$ and no factors of $\frac{1}{|\vec{k_2}|}$